# Errror using angular

Tags: angularjs, typescript

I'm trying to learn angular and I'm getting the following errors while trying to run this code.

1. Unexpected token. A constructor, method, accessor, or property was expected.
2. Left side of comma operator is unused and has no side effects.
3. Declaration or statement expected.

```
export class AppComponent {
  var app = ('app', ['ngAnimate'])

  app.controller('mainCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.boxes = [{
      name: 'Friends',
      image: 'https://source.unsplash.com/uAgLGG1WBd4/900x900'
    },{
      name: 'Free',
      image: 'https://source.unsplash.com/Cp-LUHPRpWM/900x900'
    },{
      name: 'Explore',
      image: 'https://source.unsplash.com/7BjmDICVloE/900x900'
    }, {
      name: 'Vast',
      image: 'https://source.unsplash.com/WLUHO9A_xik/900x900'
    }, {
      name: 'Playful',
      image: 'https://source.unsplash.com/b2-fBVrfx0o/900x900'
    }, {
      name: 'Grand',
      image: 'https://source.unsplash.com/Ixp4YhCKZkI/900x900'
    }, {
      name: 'Mist',
      image: 'https://source.unsplash.com/8BmNurlVR6M/900x900'
    }, {
      name: 'Sea',
      image: 'https://source.unsplash.com/6YqpFWWQsno/900x900'
    }, {
      name: 'Reach',
      image: 'https://source.unsplash.com/zFnk_bTLApo/900x900'
    }, {
      name: 'Awe',
      image: 'https://source.unsplash.com/j4PaE7E2_Ws/900x900'
    }, {
      name: 'Surf',
      image: 'https://source.unsplash.com/uohGiEVhWiQ/900x900'
    }, {
      name: 'Thrill',
      image: 'https://source.unsplash.com/ssrbaKvxaos/900x900'
    }, ];

    $scope.selected = [];
    $scope.selectBox = function(item, position) {
      $scope.selected = [{
        item: item,
        position: position
      }];
      $scope.$apply();
    }
    $scope.clearSelection = function() {
      $scope.selected = [];
    }
  })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a keyword within the first line of your class: `var`, `var` is for assigning scoped variables, inside a class you have properties.

A property is declared in Node.js inside the constructor using the `this.` keyword,*or* outside of the constructor (TypeScript).

A node.js example:

```
class AppComponent {
  constructor() {
    this.app = ('app', ['ngAnimate'])
  }
}
```

I have to admit, I think that's the least of your problems here, the code doesn't *appear* to be valid, although I could be wrong.

I've never seen `app.controller()` declared within the main scope of the class, usually this would be expected either inside a method, or as a method declaration.

Feel free to try above, make the required changes and feedback with what else needs to be fixed (as I'm almost certain you'll have issues with your next line).

In the meantime, I'll look into AngularJS (to ensure I'm not giving you the wrong information), as I've been used to working with Angular 6+ and syntax-wise, they're very different frameworks.

EDIT: If you have a link to where you found this code / learning from that would massively increase your chance of being helped.

Comment: Thank you. I got the code from this code pen link : https://codepen.io/ste-vg/pen/NALWrj

Comment: @Bimm remove the class declaration (AppComponent), the JavaScript code in the link you gave is flat/procedural, there's no classes being used, so you don't need to wrap the code inside a class (unless you really want to).

Comment: Okay. Will try that

Comment: @Bimm good stuff good luck with the project! If I recall correctly, AngularJS doesn't use many classes, whereas when  you upgrade to a later version of Angular (if you do), it's TypeScript and pretty much all classes. So depending on your style, you may wish to stick with AngularJS (imo easier to learn). Either way, good luck!